# Why can we ignore interactions between conduction electrons? And when is that approximation valid?

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics

I've heard of ignoring electron-electron interactions in metals. I want to know why that approximation is valid ? Are interactions between electrons very small compared to electron-ion interactions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of an ideal gas of non-interacting particles?

Comment: The approximation is valid if the result is ok. For Cooper pairs it isn’t, for example.

Comment: see https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node86.html

Comment: In general, the ultimate justification for any approximation in science is that the equations based on those approximations fit well with experimental observation (for some definition of "fit well" - e.g. the errors may be too small to matter for a particular application, or even too small to be detected). On the flip side, various experimental results also map out the domain of applicability - the set of circumstances where the approximation/model is appropriate. You can then understand why this is the case in theoretical terms, but it's experimental results that are the measure of things.

Comment: P.S. "Pun not intended" would be a lie

Comment: In metals, electrons are delocalized, this means that the kinetic energy is larger that the interactions, reason why Bloch's theorem works fine. This approximation is not always valid at larger interatomic distances and for a weak atomic potential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a miraculous combination of a lot of different effects that makes the approximation tolerable.

As others have noted, if, say, there is superconductivity at play, then that interaction actually cannot be neglected.

But there is indeed some fun knowledge to obtain about how we really understand the sea of electrons in a metal.

First of all, it is definitely not the case that electron-electron interaction is neglected fully. Coulomb potential is long range and is necessary to treat, or else all hell breaks loose. What is really happening is that we tend to treat each electron as if it is in a mean field of all the other electrons in the system. This is the case even in an atomic calculation. Say, in a Helium atom, the winning scheme that uses a simple wavefunction to describe the electrons, uses antisymmetric spins, so as to open up the possibility for both electrons to be in the same ground state, and then uses the variational method on the effective charge seen by the electrons to get very close to the real energy level. The very act of using a smaller effective charge than $Z=2$ is a mean field approximation; the electron-electron interaction is approximately handled, not totally neglected.

Why, then, should a mean field approximation of the electron-electron interaction be tolerable? Why would there not be a huge Coulomb contribution to the energy when the electrons get close to each other? Well, the Coulomb potential itself comes to the rescue. Precisely because it is so large and repulsive, each electron actually has a configuration hole around it that no other electron will come too near towards. That is, if you find an electron precisely localised at some point, you will not find another electron too close to there. This shows up as a correlation in the position of electrons, in a way that no "independent particle" approximation can properly capture. I mean this on top of the exchange symmetry/interaction. In more detail, a single Slater determinant may capture the exchange interaction of electrons in an atom, but it will not ever be able to capture correlation, by definition. This is because Slater determinants start by assuming that each electron is independently solving the single electron in mean field approximation problem, and not able to capture that, hey, one electron is here now, and so all the other electrons better not be near. But because of this Coulomb repulsion, really the electrons spend more time away from each other than together, and thus end up being well-described by a mean field approximation than not. In fact, when you simulate electrons in a crystal, you tend to need to reduce the exchange interaction because the correlation may weaken it.

With those out of the way, the next thing to consider is that of core v.s. valence electrons. Core electrons are tightly bound to the nuclei and are best approximated by the atomic approximations, to give ions. The valence electrons are the ones that make up the valence and conduction bands, the sea of electrons, etc. We already mentioned how, in an atomic approximation, the core electrons actually already had a mean-field approximation taking care of the electron-electron interaction. For the valence electrons, which we approximate with plane waves, the Coulomb repulsion is even weaker, because these plane waves are now spread over an even wider volume.

To treat Coulomb potential properly, we need to have the ion-ion, electron-ion, electron-electron contributions, all the long range contributions, exactly cancel each other out. (This happens automatically in the mathematics, not something we force through.) Because the ions bring with them core electrons, the huge positive charges effectively get spread out and be much shallower than the full nucleus charge. For ease of calculation, the absurd approximation is to take the ionic charges and smear them out as a uniform positive background, just like the sea of electrons, only that the positive background has no dynamics. This allows us to treat all three types of Coulomb interactions with the same plane wave mathematics. This approximation is called the Jellium model, because the uniform positive background is akin to jelly. It is highly unphysical, but it has the crazy virtue of being "exactly" solvable at any density, giving us analytical expressions for how the energy of the system behaves as a function of density. This is helpful because we can then relax the assumption that the positive charge is uniformly distributed. By having density fluctuations in the positively charged background to better approxiate the fixed ions in a real material, we can approximate actual materials quite well.

Once all these are done, you can study the sea of electrons in the plane wave model. Especially at the bigger wavelengths, the electronic plane wave is so large, that essentially the ionic size is very small compared to the plane waves themselves. Similarly, the other electrons, being huge plane waves too, average out to have very little Coulomb interaction too, as long as you get the infinite contribution part that cancels in the trio of ion-ion, electron-ion and electron-electron Coulomb interactions. This is a form of mean-field approximation, and again, it gives good results.

Thus, for both the core electrons and the valence electrons, the electron-electron interaction happens to be well-described by a mean-field approximation and, while not totally neglected, allows us to use an approximation in which each electron effectively acts independently, in a potential that is self-consistently computed from the other electrons.